# Javafx TreeView setRoot I have a exception Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TreeView.setRoot(javafx.scene.control.TreeItem)

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

i juste begin to use JavaFx for a MediaPlayer projet for school, and I need to do a VideoLibrary for movies or series + a media Player.

I am following a tutorial on treeView with Javafx and when im trying to compile my code I have this exception. "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TreeView.setRoot(javafx.scene.control.TreeItem)" because "this.treeView" is null", and one the tutorial everything is working well for him.

Hope someone could have a look one this.

Thanks you in advance for your help.

My code is working great before I implement this code

```
@FXML
    private TreeView treeView;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Movies");

        treeView.setRoot(rootItem);
    }
```

This my Main class.

```
package com.example.mediaplayer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (mouseEvent.getClickCount()==2){
                    stage.setFullScreen(true);
                }
            }
        });//FullScreen quand c'est cliqué deux fois
        stage.setTitle("MediaPlayer");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This my controller class.

```
package com.example.mediaplayer;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Binding;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.ValueAxis;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {

    private String pathFile;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;

    @FXML
    private Slider progressBar;

    @FXML
    private Slider volumeBar;

    public void choosFileMethode(ActionEvent event){
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Select a File ('.mp4') ('.avi')","*.mp4","*.avi");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        pathFile = file.toURI().toString();

        if (pathFile !=null){
            Media media = new Media(pathFile);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);



            DoubleProperty widthProp = mediaView.fitWidthProperty();
            DoubleProperty heightProp = mediaView.fitHeightProperty();

            //Ajuste la taille de la fenêtre
            widthProp.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(),"width"));
            heightProp.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(),"height"));

            mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observableValue, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {

                    progressBar.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
                }
            });

            progressBar.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(progressBar.getValue()));
                }
            });

            progressBar.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(progressBar.getValue()));
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Duration  total = media.getDuration();
                    progressBar.setMax(total.toSeconds());
                }
            });

            volumeBar.setValue(mediaPlayer.getVolume()*100);
            volumeBar.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
                @Override
                public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeBar.getValue()/100);
                }
            });
        }



        }

    public void playMethode(ActionEvent event){

        mediaPlayer.play();
        mediaPlayer.setRate(1);
    }
    public void pauseMethode(ActionEvent event){

        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
    public void stopMethode(ActionEvent event){

        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    public void slowRateMethode(ActionEvent event){

        mediaPlayer.setRate(0.5);
    }
    public void fastRateMethode(ActionEvent event){

        mediaPlayer.setRate(2);
    }

    public void forward10second(ActionEvent event){
        mediaPlayer.seek(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().add(Duration.seconds(10)));
    }
    public void downward10second(ActionEvent event){
        mediaPlayer.seek(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().add(Duration.seconds(-10)));
    }
    public void exit(ActionEvent event){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void ouvirListeDeLecture(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
        try{

            FXMLLoader listeDeLecture = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("liste-de-lecture.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Scene sceneListeLecture = new Scene(listeDeLecture.load(),320,240);
            stage.setScene(sceneListeLecture);
            stage.show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Liste de lecture methode

    @FXML
    private TreeView treeView;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Movies");

        treeView.setRoot(rootItem);
    }


    public void selectItem(ActionEvent event){

    }



}
```

This is my Main windows with the FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.mediaplayer.HelloController">
   <center>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Media">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#choosFileMethode" text="Open a file" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exit" text="Quitter" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Lecture">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Avancer" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reculer" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Lecture" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pause" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Arreter" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Précedent" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Suivant" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Audio">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Augmenter le volume" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Réduire le volume" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Couper son" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Vidéo">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Plein écran" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sous-titres">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ajouter un fichier sous-titre" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Vue">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ouvirListeDeLecture" text="Liste de lecture" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Slider fx:id="progressBar" majorTickUnit="60.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="606.0" showTickMarks="true" />
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#playMethode" text="Play">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pauseMethode" text="Pause">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="51.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#slowRateMethode" text="&lt;&lt;&lt;">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="143.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stopMethode" text="Stop">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#fastRateMethode" text="&gt;&gt;&gt;">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="186.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#downward10second" text="-10s">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="227.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#forward10second" text="+10s">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Slider fx:id="volumeBar">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="7.0" right="7.0" top="40.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Slider>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

This my second windows when your press the button "Liste de lecture" in the menu bar menu "Vue" in the menu item "Liste de lecture".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="532.0" prefWidth="747.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.mediaplayer.HelloController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <left>
      <TreeView fx:id="treeView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

And the compiler throws:

```
/Users/jul/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55822:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/18-ea+6/javafx-controls-18-ea+6.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18-ea+6/javafx-graphics-18-ea+6.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/18-ea+6/javafx-base-18-ea+6.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/18-ea+6/javafx-fxml-18-ea+6.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-web/18-ea+6/javafx-web-18-ea+6.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/18-ea+6/javafx-media-18-ea+6.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.32/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.32.jar -p /Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx-core/0.4.0/bootstrapfx-core-0.4.0.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.1/controlsfx-11.1.1.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/eu/hansolo/tilesfx/11.48/tilesfx-11.48.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/18-ea+6/javafx-controls-18-ea+6-mac.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/net/synedra/validatorfx/0.2.1/validatorfx-0.2.1.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/github/almasb/fxgl/17/fxgl-17.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-core/12.3.0/ikonli-core-12.3.0.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/github/almasb/fxgl-scene/17/fxgl-scene-17.jar:/Users/jul/Desktop/MediaPlayer/target/classes:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.12.1/jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/18-ea+6/javafx-media-18-ea+6-mac.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/github/almasb/fxgl-gameplay/17/fxgl-gameplay-17.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.12.1/jackson-core-2.12.1.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/attach/audio/4.0.9/audio-4.0.9.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-javafx/12.3.0/ikonli-javafx-12.3.0.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/attach/lifecycle/4.0.9/lifecycle-4.0.9.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/dlsc/formsfx/formsfx-core/11.3.2/formsfx-core-11.3.2.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/18-ea+6/javafx-base-18-ea+6-mac.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/github/almasb/fxgl-entity/17/fxgl-entity-17.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/attach/storage/4.0.9/storage-4.0.9.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-web/18-ea+6/javafx-web-18-ea+6-mac.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/attach/util/4.0.9/util-4.0.9.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/github/almasb/fxgl-io/17/fxgl-io-17.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.32/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.32-modular.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.12.1/jackson-databind-2.12.1.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/18-ea+6/javafx-fxml-18-ea+6-mac.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/com/github/almasb/fxgl-core/17/fxgl-core-17.jar:/Users/jul/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18-ea+6/javafx-graphics-18-ea+6-mac.jar -m com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.HelloApplication
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/jul/Desktop/MediaPlayer/target/classes/com/example/mediaplayer/hello-view.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@18-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@18-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml@18-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@18-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TreeView.setRoot(javafx.scene.control.TreeItem)" because "this.treeView" is null
    at com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.HelloController.initialize(HelloController.java:168)
    at javafx.fxml@18-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
    ... 9 more
Exception running application com.example.mediaplayer.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Don't use the same controller class for different FXML files. There is no element in `hello-view.fxml` with `fx:id="treeView"`, so when `initialize()` is invoked on the controller created when you load that FXML file, `treeView` is `null`, and you get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Oh ok thanks you James, im so dumb i didn't know about that.